# Symfony2 windows xamp mkdir Invalid Argument

Tags: windows, symfony, mkdir

I've got strange problem. I'm developing application using symfony2.8 framework it works on Ubuntu fine, but when i using windows7 and adding media i got this error:

Warning: mkdir(): Invalid argument
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

Error apears because $directory parameter of mkdir method is wrong:
it looks like:

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/my_path/web/uploads/media/default/0001/01/C:/xampp/tmp
```

Does anyone knows why path is wrong?
I'm using xamp on windows7 and symfony2.8(with sonata and media bundle)

Please help.

Comment: use another slashes in paths. windows is using \, ubuntu / as a directory separator

Comment: i know, but path above is generated automatically, inside cache folder, and i dont, know why at the end of it application adds "/C:/xampp/tmp". The part "/C:/xampp" is the problem.